# Transfer Microsoft SQL Server data to Oracle tables on daily basis

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to transfer SQL Server data to Oracle tables on a daily basis.

What's the best way to do it? I am using Windows 7 as OS and SQL Developer as a tool.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Agent Job most likely.

Comment: Try to look at SSIS (what you're trying to achieve is called an ETL - Extract Transform & Load)

Comment: Consider Oracle's Materialized views (complete refresh on a daily schedule) over a HS ODBC database link.  That's how we port non-Oracle data into our Oracle databases.

Comment: without installing licensed software, is it possible?

Comment: If you are familiar with Java. https://dbisweb.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in Export Data command to generate an SSIS package that you can then run on a daily basis.

```
1) Right click on the data base in SSMS on the Object Explorer Window.
2) Select 'Tasks' from the pop-up window.
3) Click on Export Data.
4) Choose a data source (SQL Server Data Base)
5) Choose data destination as Oracle
```

At the end of the GUI you can save it as a SSIS package. Please do so and you can then run it either as a SQL Server Agent job or at the Windows level by  using the DTEXEC command. My biggest challange when doing this is getting credentials on Oracle that allows writing and finding the correct ORA file.

Comment: without installing licensed software, is it possible to achieve above steps?

Comment: No SSIS is part of SQL Server. Once you license SQL Server SSIS is free. I am not sure about BCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a transactional replication and create a non-sql server subscriber in oracle.
See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/non-sql-server-subscribers

Or if you only need the data to be updated once a day, consider to use snapshot replication. 
Both transaction and snapshot replication can have a non-sql server subscriber.